# В верстке появляются левые компоненты

Tags: битрикс

Я делаю сайт в 1с битрикс. Когда я натянула верстку на битрикс, внизу рядом с футером начали выскакивать красные сообщения и какая то непонятная форма, которой быть вообще не должно. Как я могу это убрать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пути  к стилям неправильно прописаны